# Parse time with SimapleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, time, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse date like this: Tue Aug 28 21:16:23 +0000 2012 with this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E M dd HH:mm:ssZ yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
String d = object.getString("created_at"); // d = Tue Aug 28 21:16:23 +0000 2012;
date = format.parse(d);
```

But there is exception:

```
09-28 11:10:24.471: W/System.err(10388): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Sep 28 07:09:09 +0000 2012" (at offset 4)
```

Where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

`MMM` is used to represent short Month.

Comment: Thank you, it's work, but there is one more mistake:E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy. Space between ss and Z. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

you need MMM for month representation for Aug.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ssZ yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String d = "Tue Aug 28 21:16:23 +0000 2012"; // d =;
        Date date = format.parse(d);
                System.out.println(date);
```

Output:Tue Aug 28 22:16:23 BST 2012

It might help to look into [SimpleDateFormat's javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), there are some helpful examples for pattern strings.

Comment: Thank you, it's work, but there is one more mistake:E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy. Space between ss and Z.